# Bridge recitifier circuit for 3-phase system

Tags: voltage, power, current, ac, three-phase

I want to design a three-phase AC- charger board.

The three phases and neutral come from a connector.

Can someone tell me how to build (what components to choose) a 3-phase rectifier circuit, so that these 3-phase goes as an output for the charging.

Also, I require this 3-phase input to feed an AC-DC module. This DC module would power the other MCUs & ICs in the board.

How to design? Any suggestions/inputs will be helpful.

Comment: Three-phase diode rectifier bridges are readily available, so other than recommending you look for one of those there's not enough information to go any further.  If you can add your voltage, current, frequency and ripple requirements then you might get more specific recommendations.

Comment: A bridge rectifier would not result in sinusoidal input currents - not when feeding a single step-up converter, much less when feeding a traditional choke-input filter, let alone a capacitor input one. `AC-DC module [to power other electronics]` "precludes" using a DC/DC converter from the *bus voltage*. *charger* as in multi-kW battery charger?

Comment: @JohnD, thank you for your suggestion. It is for a EVSE L2 Charge controller. For a reference, can you check this app note, and let me know your suggestions. https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidub87/tidub87.pdf?ts=1691041222817&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsitesearch%252Fen-us%252Fdocs%252Funiversalsearch.tsp%253FlangPref%253Den-US%2526searchTerm%253Dtidub87%2526nr%253D9

Comment: For that kind of application you would want a power factor corrected front end as @greybeard suggests.  That's beyond the scope of a simple question here I think.

Comment: @JohnD, could you, could you please tell me or direct me to some link where I get the circuits/modules?

Comment: @Freshman Take a look at this for the general idea.  There are other topologies as well: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/and9957-d.pdf

Comment: @JohnD, thank you. Do you have any other links that can explain in simple terms please/

Comment: A high power 3-phase PFC can be difficult design even for those of us who are experienced power electronics designers.  If you're not familiar with the concept of PFC it's maybe not a good idea to try a 3 phase high power PFC as a first project.  You can Google "active power factor correction" and "three phase power factor correction" to learn more.

Comment: @JohnD, thank you for the direction. Just a question. I am curious to know the specifications of a three phase system. What is the mains voltage and what would the maximum current? Could you please help me to show where it is mentioned in this app note: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidub87/tidub87.pdf?ts=1691041222817&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsitesearch%252Fen-us%252Fdocs%252Funiversalsearch.tsp%253FlangPref%253Den-US%2526searchTerm%253Dtidub87%2526nr%253D9

Comment: Definitions at the end of p.2 and also page 3: This implementation of an EVSE contains a basic set of features, which are expandable to enable
additional usage scenarios. The primary functionality includes:
• Level 1 and level 2 operation (120 V to 240 V)
• Power delivery up to 30 A (expandable with larger relays)